# How to set state_output=changes in a salt-stack schedule?

Tags: salt-stack

I have a salt schedule calling state.apply and using the highstate returner to write out a file.  The schedule is being kicked off as expected, and the output file is being created, but all the unchanged states are included in the output.

On the command line, I'd force only diffs and errors to be with the `--state_output=changes` option of salt.

Is there a way to include set `state_output=changes` in the schedule somehow ?

My defining the schedule in the pillar data and it looks something like this:

```
schedule:
  mysched:
    function: state.apply
    seconds: 3600
    kwargs:
      test: True
    returner: highstate
    returner_kwargs:
      report_format: yaml
      report_delivery: file
      file_output: /path/to/mysched.yaml
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by switching the schedule as per below.  Instead of calling state.apply directly, the schedule uses cmd.run to to kick off a salt-call command that does the state.apply, and that command can include the state-output flag.

```
schedule:
  mysched:
    function: cmd.run
    args:
    - "salt-call state.apply --state-output=changes --log-level=warning test=True > /path/to/mysched.out 2>&1"
    seconds: 3600
```